# Can not install any color scheme in Vim in Kubuntu

Tags: vim, kde, kubuntu

I have installed the latest Kubuntu. I am trying to set a nice color scheme for my terminal, but it does not work.For example I tried [wombat256](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2465). I copied the wombat256mod.vim under `~/.vim/colors` as it is specified in the instructions and did: `:colorscheme wombat256mod`. There is no change in vim. By default `TERM` is set to xterm. Trying `TERM=xterm-256color vim` does not work either.

I have also tried solarized and github theme, no change. I am using the default Kubuntu terminal. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Braiam:Yes. I am using Konsole which was installed by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet you downloaded the [wombat256mod.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=13400) file and tried to add with `:colorscheme wombat256` instead of `:colorscheme wombat256mod`. You must watch that both files has different endings. The `:colorscheme wombat256mod` will only work for the [wombat256mod.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=13400) file while `:colorscheme wombat256` will only work for [wombat256](http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=13397) file. Try again but with `:colorscheme wombat256mod` and it will work.